# Difficulty to run simple GWT application on tomcat server

Tags: gwt

I am creating a gwt application as following steps:
First install gwt plugin in my eclipse(Helios).
Create GWT project
Add Dynamic web plugin
going to property page of the project
project Facets tab
Select Dynamic Web Module and java
ok to apply changes.
Write code
and i try to run on server tomcat7 then it shows resources not available.But when i run as internal server of gwt as just right clicking on project and selecting run as web application.
then it run successfully. so please help to run my application on tomcat server.
Thanks
Rahul

Comment: hey try to get war file from your project and placed it in the bin folder of tomcat directory might it worked ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you Compile your Application? (GWT Compile Project)

You can then run [this](http://pastebin.com/0TJDGSPp) Ant buildfile and deploy the WAR file on your Tomcat Server.